# Where is the "LINQ to SQL Overview" video featuring Luca Bolognese?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, video, msdn

I very much like the said video on LINQ, as it is very instructive to newbies on LINQ and I often shared that link. However, the video is no longer available (as it was) via the following link:

http://www.microsoft.com/emea/msdn/spotlight/sessionh.aspx?videoid=716

,which is referred to from
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucabol/archive/2008/03/03/linq-to-sql-overview-video.aspx

**Where can I find a copy of that video?** Extensive Googling lead to no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this video is Luca's session from TechEd 2007 in Barcelona you should find it here (stream + WMV download):

> **[MSDN Webcast: The .NET Language Integrated Query (LINQ) Framework (Level 300)](http://www.microsoft.com/events/series/teched07.aspx?tab=Webcasts&seriesid=96&webcastid=2278)**

Comment: Sorry, just noticed that this is from TechEd Orlando, so it's probably not what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you so much. Even this is not exactly the one I was looking for (with Luca walking around smiling), this does serve my needs.